# Hibernate Core daily/weekly build Maven repository

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

I'm looking for a Maven repository that contains daily or weekly builds of Hibernate Core. More specifically I'm trying to get a hibernate-core build that contains a [bug fix](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3636) which was checked-in on December 9, 2008. Unfortunately the most recent hibernate-core is 3.3.1GA built during September, 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Maven Guide for Hibernate Core [here](http://www.hibernate.org/422.html), it explains configuring your project for the snapshot repository. The current 3.4.0 snapshot has been taken on January 21st (see http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/).